# SSL for OpenLDAP on Centos 7 not working

Tags: ssl, centos7, openldap

I'm currently trying to configure SSL for OpenLDAP on Centos 7 with a self signed certificate. LDAP works without SSL. I made following commands:

Generating the certificate / key and changing ownership:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -out /etc/openldap/certs/ldap.cert -keyout /etc/openldap/certs/ldap.key -days 730
chown -R ldap:ldap /etc/openldap/certs/ldap*
```

Creating the ldif file to publish the certificate changes:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/ldap.key

dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/ldap.cert
```

Publishing the changes with `ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f certs.ldif`

After that I update `/etc/sysconfig/slapd` like that:

```
SLAPD_URLS="ldapi:/// ldap:/// ldaps:///"
```

I restarted the `slapd` daemon and checked that LDAP is listening on port 636, which it does.

On the client I installed the packages `openldap-clients` and `nss-pam-ldapd`. I configured the host so that I can login with my LDAP users:

```
authconfig --enableldap --enableldapauth --ldapserver=ldaps://ldap.local --ldapbasedn="dc=ldap,dc=local" --enablemkhomedir --disableldaptls --update
```

In the `/etc/nslcd.conf` I added `tls_reqcert` to allow self signed certificates.

Finally if I try to get the user information with `getent passwd user` it return nothing as output. The user does exist in the LDAP directory. If I try to do `ldapsearch` I get the following error:

```
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

I'm not really sure what I can do to fix the problem at this point.

Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards,

Markus

Comment: There are comments at the bottom of that article with other people saying they have the same problem. Do any of their solutions there fix the problem for you?

Comment: @bodgit the first part works now, but I still can't connect to the LDAP server

Comment: How are you connecting to the LDAP server? Does setting `LDAPTLS_REQCERT=allow` beforehand then make it work? If so you need to either trust or ignore the server certificate using the relevant entry in either `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` or `~/.ldaprc`.

Comment: @bodgit I configured what you suggested, but it still doesn't change anything. I configured the ldap server with `authconfig` and did try to get the user with `getent passwd`. The error in my initial post shows up when I try `ldapsearch` for the user.

Comment: Did this work before you configured SSL? It's far easier to debug as you go rather than follow two fairly large HOWTO's and then debug why it doesn't work at the end. FYI you will need to either `export LDAPTLS_REQCERT=allow` in your shell or prefix your `ldapsearch ...` command with `LDAPTLS_REQCERT=allow` in order for that setting to have any effect; that setting should prevent trying to validate the server certificate. It's also better to actually paste the full commands you're attempting into the question rather than someone having to refer to something buried in one of the HOWTO's.

Comment: @bodgit LDAP works without using SSL. If I export the parameter, then the error changes to just `ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)`, with the additional info gone. Are there any logs for LDAP I may find further information on what may be wrong?
I also will update the main post, to make it more clear what commands I used.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that OpenLDAP server shipped with RHEL/CentOS is linked against Mozilla's libnss but the cert/key files you're using are only suitable for OpenSSL lib. libnss requires a passphrase in the "key" file and cert file pointing to a libnss cert/key DB.

Because [Red Hat will drop package *openldap-servers* from their distribution](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/7.4_release_notes/chap-red_hat_enterprise_linux-7.4_release_notes-deprecated_functionality#idp7516056) anyway I'd strongly recommend to use the RPMs compiled by the LDAP Toolbox Project which are linked against OpenSSL:

[LTB Project -- OpenLDAP RPMs / Yum repository](https://www.ltb-project.org/documentation/openldap-rpm#yum_repository)

LTB RPMs install OpenLDAP components completely separated from OS packages into /usr/local/openldap. So the LTB RPMs do not conflict with other OpenLDAP packages.

Note that the default path of the ldapi:// socket of the LTB builds is also located beneath /usr/local/openldap. So e.g. instead of using ldapmodify you should use /usr/local/openldap/bin/ldapmodify.

Please consult the [OpenLDAP Software 2.4 Administrator's Guide](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/) to understand how to setup an OpenLDAP server from scratch. While this seems seems harder than using a prepared config of an OS package it gives you a better understanding of OpenLDAP config methods leading to more robust operation.

Comment: Do I only have to replace the openldap-servers package with one you linked? Or are other save to remove as well? (like openldap-servers-sql or openldap-devel)

Comment: I've edited my answer to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: While installing I get following error:

    `Transaction check error:
    file /usr/lib/systemd/system/slapd.service from install of openldap-ltb-2.4.46-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openldap-servers-2.4.44-15.el7_5.x86_64`

Comment: I got to start the 'new' slapd with the `slapd-cli` script in systemd (still needed to uninstall `openldap-servers` though). But now I really don't know how to configure the server. When I try to follow the normal tutorials with `ldapmodify` and such commands (even using the ones under `/usr/local`) I always get `ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)` I never had in the past.

Comment: Probably it's because of LDAPI socket pathname. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I already used the commands under `/usr/local/openldap/bin`, but I'm still getting the same error as posted above.

Comment: Ok it seems like I need to use the value from `LDAPI_SOCKETURL` in the `slapd-cli.conf` file. Now I at least don't get the connection error. But I'm still not sure what I need to configure. It seems like I have to define the root DN and user in the `slapd.conf` file, instead of using `ldapadd`. Is that right? I also can't add the schema file like `cosine.ldif`, because I'm getting following error: `ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to emphasize that it's IMO important for you to fully understand how OpenLDAP config works as a whole. It does not make sense to answer all detail questions which will arise during that journey.

Comment: I understand that it would be best to fully understand OpenLDAP. But sometimes you just don't have the time to read the admin guide to the fullest. My problem with the openldap-ltb package is that just nothing works, which already worked with the normal openldap package. Things like `ldapmodify` giving `insufficient access` errors, which I never had while configuring the other package.

Comment: The point about the certificates being in the wrong format isn't actually true. While it will use the NSS format, the RHEL OpenLDAP packages also work fine using PEM-encoded files.

Answer (score 0):

Check `/usr/libexec/openldap/create-certdb.sh` to create `/etc/ldap/certs/` files.

This should generate proper files, as far as I remember it uses `/etc/pki/` as source. But I'm not 100% sure on that.